# Python mechanize to fill form with variables or extracted text

Tags: python, forms, submit, controls, mechanize

I am trying to make a script  with python mechanize to fill a form automatically.  With values that changes according to other factors. Is there a way i can make it read from files? This is my code:

```
br.open('https://url/url)
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['xxxxx']='123456'
br.form['yyyyy']='7890'
br.submit()                                           
print br.response().read()
```

How can i get something like

br.form['xxxx']=open(xxx.txt,r)

so it reads from xxx.txt and fill the form..  Cant seems to find anything on the web...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
br.form['xxxx']=open(xxx.txt,r).read()
```

This will give the content of file directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if txt file has one line.

```
br.open(url)
br.select_form(nr=0)
with open('example.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        br.form['xxxxx']= line
br.form['yyyyy']='7890'
response = br.submit()
search = response.read()
```

For the other hand:

```
br.open(url)
br.select_form(nr=0)
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('example.txt')]
br.form['xxxxx']= lines[0]
br.form['yyyyy']= lines[1]
response = br.submit()
search = response.read()
```